# How to catch a component exception in Talend?

Tags: java, talend

I have a `Talend` job that loops through several different files and send them with a `tFTPPut`, this is the problematic part:

```
tFixedFlowInput ===(Main)==> tFlowToIterate ===(Iterate)==> tJavaFlex ===(Iterate)==> tFtpConnection ===(OncomponentError)==>tWarn
```

If the connection is successful the job sends the file.

The job stops if there is an error after the `tJavaFlex` and in order to just go to the next iteration and send the next file whether the error is on the `tFtpConnection` or any other component I used a try & catch in the `tJavaFlex`.

My problem now is that I already have `tWarns` linked to other components with an `OncomponentError` that I would like to have in my logs. Catching the exception just restarts the loop and go to the next iteration without going to the `tWarn` and the exception itself isn't always that clear.

Is there a way to catch the exception of a particular component?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason for you to open FTPConnection inside a loop?
The ideal is to open a connection first and then use a subjob trigger to loop through the files you need to upload.

See below image:

[Talend job FTPPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDc2g.png)

Comment: This should probably be a comment, not an answer.